# Install Ubuntu 20.04LTS in AMD AMD Ryzen 9 5900HX

Tags: 20.04, ssh

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my laptop (hardware specifications: AMD Ryzen 9 5900HX CPU, Nvidia 3070).

After reboot, The system freezes during the bootup screen.
But the System is ready and the network is ready too.

My question is why can't I enter the desktop environment — not even the virtual consoles (`Ctrl+Alt+F1-F7`)
But I can ping the system IP which is given by the DHCP server.

Is there any other way to login in the system, so I can install ssh-server or any other way that I can install ssh-server when I set up Ubuntu?
It looks like Ubuntu 20.04 doesn't support the AMD Ryzen 9 5900HX Integrated graphics processor.

Comment: Are you seeing any "grub" menus? Might this perhaps be a problem with your display / display drivers if you aren't seeing anything? Or is the system really getting suck in bios?

Comment: No, I don't see grub menus. After install my OS remove the usb installer and press enter to reboot. The machine will reboot and stuck in AMI bios logo. I'm sure the machine install success because the DHCP can assign the IP to the mac address. And I can ping the IP address.

Comment: Have you tried connecting your laptop to an external monitor or TV? You mention it might be an issue with the integrated graphics - maybe the nvidia dedicated card can still be used?

Comment: Maybe try last time. The machine was transferred to another place.

Comment: Let us know if the monitor solution works for you, otherwise we might need more info to help you out. If you've solved your issue, be sure to answer your question with your solution or close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I test install Ubuntu 20.04 on new ssd.
In this time, I connected HDMI monitor without laptop panel.
The monitor show finally. The HDMI module with 3070 run with nouveau driver.

It's look like the BIOS setting with dGPU only causing this problem.
The display came to monitor.

Thanks @zzzach